# Scheduling task without memory leak

Tags: go

I have created a scheduler which run every 10 seconds using golang newTicker. 
Each tick creates a new goroutine which performs some memory intensive task but finishes well before 10 seconds are completed.

I have deployed this in kubernetes. container has both scheduler and http server. HTTP server will take a single request and run the schedule once. This is for retrying missed tasked manually. Code is as follows:

```
func startScheduledTask() {
    fmt.Println("Task Started...", time.Now())
    ticker := time.NewTicker(10 * time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    for ; true; <-ticker.C {
        go customTask(time.Now())       
    }
}
```

I observed that this code is not releasing memory. Docker stats for container shows the memory is growing. Though it has memory limit on k8s, and k8s will restart in case of OOMKilled, one scheduled tasked is still missed and manual intervention is required. Is there a way to release this memory?

customTask Code is making HTTP Request for each tick.

Docker stats and container logs are as follows.

[Docker stats and container log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t06U.jpg)

Comment: What is your customTask doing. The code here shouldn't leak memory so it might be something in there. Does it exit the function when it completes?

Comment: Also as an aside you can range over the channel rather than having to have a for loop with true https://gobyexample.com/range-over-channels

Comment: @lain Duncan For loop true is required becuase first tick should be immediate and then it should wait for 10 seconds, If i only use range then first tick is delayed by 10 seconds. Custom task code is as follows . it is just dummy since before executing in prod I need to debug that memory issue.

Comment: ```func customTask(t time.Time) {

 fmt.Println("Tick at ", t)
 var s []int
 for i := 1; i < 500000; i++ {
  s = append(s, 0)
 }

}```

Comment: A more idiomatic way to write the loop is `for { go customTask(time.Now()); <-ticker.C }`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Leaking goroutines were culprits. used https://github.com/bcicen/grmon and found out that number of goroutines were increasing along with scheduler ticks. They were waiting at net/http package.

**response.body.close(**)  and **Transport.CloseIdleConnections()** fixed the issue. NewTicker works fine. Thanks

Fix should be applied after we make http call.

```
if err == nil && statusCode == http.StatusOK {
            httpSuccess = true
            //fmt.Println("httpSuccess", httpSuccess)

            tr.CloseIdleConnections()
            return response, nil
        }
```

```
    if response.Body != nil {
        if err := response.Body.Close(); err != nil {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not need to call `CloseIdleConnections` under normal circumstances. Chances are you’re not properly handing responses or transports.

Comment: This describes a fix to code that was never given in the original question, so it is unlikely to help future users that might land on this in a search. Can you update the question and/or answer to provide enough context for this to be useful to others?

Comment: @Adrian Question Updated

Comment: The quoted code in the question doesn't show anywhere where the stated fixes could be applied.

Comment: @Adrian, Updated answer